# RUnnin a customized plan in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

I often have to run a customized plan in Bamboo (the same one every time).  So I find the plan, do a run customized and change the environment variables and test file and do a run.  This is OK but it gets old.  Is there a way to save the customized plan so I can run it?  Or save the changes so when I run customize plan I can select that?

Comment: Is running from CLI while passing in the environment variables an option?

Answer (score 0):

You can create plan branch and override variable for it